# Refresh list retrieved from Apex based on an event from another component in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to fire an event from an lwc where users upload a file using lightning-fileUpload which refreshes the Files related list in another lwc.

Is used the pubsub model to fire an event when a user uploads a file using the "onuploadfinished" event and call a javascript method which used refreshApex to refresh a list of files.

I can't seem to figure why its not working. Any help is appreciated.

HTML LWC 1:

```
<lightning-file-upload 
       label="Attach file"
       accept={acceptedFormats}
       record-id={recordId}
       onuploadfinished={handleUploadFinished}
>
</lightning-file-upload>
```

JS LWC1:

```
handleUploadFinished(event) {
  // Get the list of uploaded files
     const uploadedFiles = event.detail.files;

     tagUploaded({docId: uploadedFiles[0].documentId, value: 
                  this.selectedValue});
        this.selectedValue = '';
        this.displayUpload = false;

        fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'refreshFilesList');
    }
```

JS LWC2:

```
connectedCallback() {
    // subscribe to inputChangeEvent event
    registerListener('refreshFilesList', this.refreshList, this);
}

refreshList() {
    return refreshApex(this.relatedFiles);
}
```